# FactoryGirl sequence not incrementing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryGirl to create instances of a date dimension model for a Rails-related gem. My factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :next_day do |n|
    Date.new(2000,12,31) + n.days
  end

  factory :date_dimension do
    the_date = FactoryGirl.generate(:next_day)
    date {the_date.to_s}
    calendar_year {the_date.strftime("%Y")}
    (...other attributes created similarly to calendar_year)
  end

end
```

Out of frustration I actually built a little test to show what's not working:

```
describe "working date factories" do
  before(:all) do
    @date_dimension = FactoryGirl.create(:date_dimension)
    @jan_two = FactoryGirl.create(:date_dimension)
  end

  describe "sequence incrementing" do
    it "returns a date dimension object ok" do
      @date_dimension.date.should == "2001-01-01"
    end
    it "returns the next date in the sequence" do
      @jan_two.date.should == "2001-01-02"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run that test, I get:

```
working date factories
  sequence incrementing
    returns a date dimension object ok
    returns the next date in the sequence (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) working date factories sequence incrementing returns the next date in the sequence
     Failure/Error: @jan_two.date.should == "2001-01-02"
       expected: "2001-01-02"
            got: "2001-01-01" (using ==)
```

I've read a bunch of other questions related to sequences, but it doesn't seem that I'm making the mistakes identified therein. It's a different (likely dumber) mistake. What is it?

Comment: I really can't reproduce your problem. I tried defining an almost identical factory and it worked with sequence just fine. I then suspected it may be related to the use of the block and a local variable inside the :date_dimension factory but to no avail.. For me it worked just fine..

Comment: Mmmmm, does the counter starts at 0?

Comment: My theory was that if the first example passes, that indicates that the counter is starting at 1, since 12/31/2000 + 1.day should be 1/1/2001. It passes, so I think that shows the counter starts at 1.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an approach that works, and is probably a little better anyway. I still don't understand why the code above doesn't work - if someone can explain that to me (maybe with a reference to a doc or part of the source code), I'll go ahead and accept that answer - this post is just for those who follow. Here's what worked:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :date_dimension do
    sequence(:date) { |n| (Date.new(2000,12,31) + n.days).to_s }
    calendar_year { Date.parse(date).strftime("%Y") }
    day_of_week { Date.parse(date).strftime("%A") }
  end

end
```

The code above passes this test:

```
describe "working date factories" do
  before(:all) do
    @date_dimension = FactoryGirl.create(:date_dimension)
    @jan_two = FactoryGirl.create(:date_dimension)
  end

  describe "sequences" do
    it "returns the proper first date in the sequence" do
      @date_dimension.date.should == "2001-01-01"
      @date_dimension.calendar_year.should == "2001"
      @date_dimension.day_of_week.should == "Monday"
    end
    it "returns the next date in the sequence" do
      @jan_two.date.should == "2001-01-02"
      @jan_two.calendar_year.should == "2001"
      @jan_two.day_of_week.should == "Tuesday"
    end
  end
end
```